User is able to select multiple radio buttons incorrectly
This is the view of my quiz app in ASP.NET Core:
<div class="question bg-white p-3 border-bottom">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center question-title">
        <h3 class="text-primary">Q.</h3>
        <h5 class="mt-1 ml-2">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.q_text)</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="ans ml-2">
        <label class="radio">
            <span>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.QA, Model.q_id, new { id = "QA" })
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                @Model.QA
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="ans ml-2">
        <label class="radio">
            <span>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.QB, Model.q_id, new { id = "QB" })
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                @Model.QB
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="ans ml-2">
        <label class="radio">
            <span>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.QC, Model.q_id, new { id = "QC" })
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                @Model.QC
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="ans ml-2">
        <label class="radio">
            <span>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.QD, Model.q_id, new { id = "QD" })
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                @Model.QD
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>


    <div class="row" style="display:none">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.QCorrectAns)
    </div>

</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center p-3 bg-white">
    <input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-success" />
    @Html.ValidationMessage("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

I tried to apply Options names instead Model.q_id but it didn't work.
In the above code User is able to select multiple options, which leads to an error or wrong answer selection. I don't want to allow that user to select multiple options.
I want that user to only be able to select one option at a time.
Model Class
public int q_id { get; set; }
public string q_text { get; set; }
public string QA { get; set; }
public string QB { get; set; }
public string QC { get; set; }
public string QD { get; set; }
public string QCorrectAns { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> q_fk_Cat_id { get; set; }
    
public virtual quiz_Category quiz_Category { get; set; }


Hi, can you share your model class? What is your QA, QB, and so on?

The first argument of RadioButtonFor() must be the same for all radio buttons in a group. It is the property to which the chosen radio button will be bound when processing the form submission. It would be clearer if you just used the actual HTML tags (name attribute must be the same for all radios in a group). See this article for more info: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/radios And this one for general info on HTML radio buttons: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

That is to say, your page model should have ONE property that will receive the value of the chosen radio button, NOT one property per button. In the first article I linked, they use an array to store the available options and a single string for the selected choice.

Are you accept not using the RadioButtonFor? I mean using the input type="radio" not use RadioButtonFor.

@yongShun i shared it above


then i have to specify the id for it and need to write the JavaScript code.

No, I mean using the ASP.NET Core tag helper to achieve your requirement. Inside HTML input tag radio button, it will use name to see if this is a group or not. So if you are using the tag helper you should set asp-for attribute for the q_id, it will auto set all the name to the q_id.
Like this :
      <input type="radio" asp-for="q_id" value="@Model.QA" />  

More details, you could refer to below example:
My controller code:
    public IActionResult Index()
    {


        var model = new quizModel() { QA="1", QB="2", QC="3", QD="4"};

        return View(model);
    }

View codes:
    <form asp-action="test" method="post">
    
    
        <div class="question bg-white p-3 border-bottom">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center question-title">
                <h3 class="text-primary">Q.</h3>
                <h5 class="mt-1 ml-2">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.q_text)</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="ans ml-2">
                <label class="radio">
                    <span>
                        @* @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.QA, 0, new { id = "QA", name = "q_id" }) *@
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="q_id" value="@Model.QA" />  
                        
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        @Model.QA
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="ans ml-2">
                <label class="radio">
                    <span>
                       @*  @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.QB, 1, new { id = "QB", name = "q_id" }) *@
    
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="q_id" value="@Model.QB" />  
    
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        @Model.QB
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="ans ml-2">
                <label class="radio">
                    <span>
                        @* @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.QC, 2, new { id = "QC", name = "q_id" }) *@
    
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="q_id" value="@Model.QC" /> 
    
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        @Model.QC
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="ans ml-2">
                <label class="radio">
                    <span>
                        @* @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.QD, 3, new { id = "QD", name = "q_id" }) *@
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="q_id" value="@Model.QD" /> 
    
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        @Model.QD
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="row" style="display:none">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.QCorrectAns)
            </div>
    
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </div>
</form>
  

Result:



I tried to use input type but it's not working.

You are using the asp.net core MVC right? Could you please post your current codes?

I mean we should use asp.net core tag helper.  Do you use the tag helper?

Yes i tried using tag helper but its not work.

Since my test codes working, I need your codes which could reproduce the issue and let me test at my side to see why your codes doesn't work.
